# Why is NotificationManager not accepting my notification

Tags: android, compiler-errors, notifications

I am unable to get [NotificationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html)'s [Notifiy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#notify(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.app.Notification)) accept my arguments. The method is supposed to take 3 arguments.

```
String        tag
int           id
Notification  notification
```

[image]

For constructing the notification, I am using the [NotificationCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html) class, but I've tried even [Notification.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html).

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
```

Regarding my build configuration, it is as follows:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

minSdkVersion 14
targetSdkVersion 21
```

EDIT: Code transcript:

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

private void showNotification(Context context, String category, String title, String text, int tag, boolean ongoing)
{
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_SET_NEW_PASSWORD);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, new Random().nextInt(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setContentTitle(title);
    builder.setContentText(text);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setOngoing(ongoing);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notificationManager.showNotification(context, category, title, text, new Random().nextInt(), ongoing);
    notificationManager.notify(null, 0, notification);
}
```

Comment: where is notificationManager initialisation?

Comment: Are you using `NotificationManagerCompat`?

Comment: Can you post the code as text instead of image please

Comment: I've added a code transcript.

Comment: Copied your code, but I can't reproduce the problem

Comment: The problem is already solved, the mistake was using `NotificationManager` instead of `NotificationCompatManager`. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: i had the same error and later i noticed that notification was the name of my service. just in case someone has the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the Compat version `NotificationManagerCompat`, initialize it `notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());`. And after that, notify the manager `notificationManager.notify(null, 0, notification);`

```
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

...

private NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;

...

// onCreate
notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());

...

// Somewhere in your code
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("I'm a title")
    .setContentText("Some text")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .build();

notificationManager.notify(null, 0, notification);
```

Comment: You are using `NotificationManager `, but you should use `NotificationManagerCompat`.

Comment: Indeed, you are right, I missed that, sorry :) I was writing this based on the official guide. Possible mistake there referemcing the normal `NotificationManger` http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

Comment: @MartinRončka This may not be the real issue, something else is going on here. Otherwise it would not tell you `notify() in Object` but `notify() in NotificationManager`

Comment: @Tim Castelijns, this is working and tested as working.

Comment: @Exaqt I'm not saying it's not working. I'm saying the error message and the proposed solution don't match. If this is the solution, the error message makes no sense

Comment: @Tim Castelijns indeed the error message indicates that the notificationManager is of type object. Maybe it is sdk version issue?

Answer (score 3):

> notify in Object

this part of the 'error' message hints that your notificationManager is an Object, and that you declared it like this

```
Object notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

What you should have is this

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Nice catch on that

Comment: I do have declared notificationManager of type NotificationManager, sorry for not including that in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

Check the imports. This is what I have been using.

```
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
```

For the function -

```
private void createNotification(String idString, String title, String body, boolean isSound,
                                    boolean isVibration, PendingIntent intent) {
        Context context = getBaseContext();
        Bitmap mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.styfi_largenotify);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.styfi_notify)
                .setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setLargeIcon(mIcon)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentIntent(intent)
                .setLights(Color.CYAN, 3000, 3000)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        if (isSound)
            mBuilder.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
        if (isVibration)
            mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 500, 500});

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        String actual = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < idString.length(); i++) {
            char c = idString.charAt(i);
            int value;
            try{
                value = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                value = Math.abs(c - 'a' + 1);
            }
            actual += String.valueOf(value);
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                Log.d(TAG, "char = [" + c + "], value = [" + value + "], actual = [" + actual + "]");
        }

        BigInteger idBigInt = new BigInteger(actual);
        int id = Math.abs(idBigInt.intValue());

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "idLong = [" + idBigInt +"], id = [" + id + "]");
        mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

Comment: Problem already solved, the mistake was using `NotificationCompat.Builder` and old `NotificationManager`. Fixed that to `NotificationCompatManager`.